# Create Shell Script for Mac that is the same as my BAT file

Tags: shell, batch-file, ffmpeg

I have written a batch file to add two images as watermarks onto each video within a directory, now I need that converted to a shell script so I can run it on a Mac.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("*.MP4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i ../soccer5s.png -i ../vpa.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" "%%~na-marked.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. Show us what you've tried, and *exactly* where you're stuck. (Which specific part of the syntax do you need help converting to bash? How does what you've already tried fail?) See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything, first install `ffmpeg`. Using **homebrew** is easiest, and you can install that from [here](https://brew.sh).

Having installed **homebrew**, do the following to install `ffmpeg`:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Now save this as `go` in your `$HOME` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't barf if no MP4 files and also do MP4 as well as mp4
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for f in *mp4; do
   echo Processing file $f...
   ffmpeg -i "$f" ../soccer5s.png -i ../vpa.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" "${f}-marked.mp4"
done
```

Now start Terminal and make the script executable. You only need do this once:

```
cd
chmod +x go
```

Now change directory to somewhere where you have some MP4 files:

```
cd some/where/with/MP4/files
```

and run with:

```
$HOME/go
```